# How are Probability and Non Determinism Related ? Alternatives to handle Non determinism?

Tags: automata, probability-theory, nondeterminism

I have been thinking about Non-determinism in any kind of state machine. Since I work on machine learning, I tend to think that probability is a means of handling non-determinism. Instead of exhaustively taking every possible transition  to arrive at a solution we prioritize the alternatives.

I just wonder if there are works that has compared both Probability and Non-determinism and the adequacy of probability based approaches in handling Non-determinism?

I am also interested in knowing are there other alternatives in handling non-determinism. For  example, if I can clone a state and add more context or features to both the states to eliminate then woudlnt that be more hlepful. I consider this from a constraint logic point of view, where we add further constraints from additional resources. So by this we add only constraints whenever non-determinism arises, thus saving us from exhaustive search which otherwise should have done.

I am sorry that this appears more like a rambling, but if anyone could direct me to some works where there are works which has studied the aspects that I am discussing in a more principled way, it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you believe that $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{BPP}$ whereas $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, then randomness unfortunately cannot simulate nondeterminism.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - I am not dealing with randomness here. I see Nondeterminism as a choice. Now my question is cant using probabilistic assignments to transition is a means of dealing with non -determinism? If so what can be other alternatives